# What Does the ANTLR ParseTree accept() method do?

Tags: java, antlr, visitor-pattern

I´m studying how to build a typechecker using ANTLR´s Tree walker. I saw there´s an accept method. This method is sometimes used  in compilers books when showing examples of a type checker implementation

```
public Type visit(Plus n) {
if (! (n.e1.accept(this) instanceof IntegerType) )
error.complain("Left side of LessThan must be of type integer");
if (! (n.e2.accept(this) instanceof IntegerType) )
error.complain("Right side of LessThan must be of type integer");
return new IntegerType();
}
```

That piece of code is from the book Modern Compiler Implementation In Java. But I don´t really understand what n.e1.accept(this) does.Every node of the tree has this method in ANTLR.

I´ve checked ANTLR v4 docs and the explanation is not really clear;

```
The ParseTreeVisitor needs a double dispatch method.
```

Can someone explain me what this does?

**EDIT:**

I researched a bit more and it is not an ANTLR specific question, I think this can be considered as a duplicate question so maybe it is a good idea to remove it:

[What is the point of accept() method in Visitor pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132178/what-is-the-point-of-accept-method-in-visitor-pattern)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an internal implementation a visitor pattern. You can safely ignore it. You should subclass YOURGRAMMARBaseVisitor or YOURGRAMMARBaseListener.

Comment: Why is it used in the method I showed in the question ? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: That accept method is how visitors will visit their children e1 and e2 in this case. This is off-topic however because it has nothing to do with ANTLR.