# Is accept() necessary when implementing Visitor design pattern in python?

Tags: python, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

I found many people implement Visitor design pattern in python as follows:

```
class Node(object):
    def accept(self, visitor):
        visitor.visit(self)
    # some code ...
class Visitor(object):
    def visit(self, node):
        # invoke corresponding method according to the type of node
        # ...

node = Node()
visitor = Vistor()
node.accept(visitor)
```

For Java or other C-like static language, they use `accept()` to implement multi-dispatch. Because the `visit()` method choose specific override method only by the static type of reference. For example:

```
public class MyVisitor implements IVisitor {
    void visit(AddNode node);
    void visit(Node node);
}
Node node = AddNode(); // AddNode is derived from Node
new MyVisitor().visit(root);
```

The visitor will invoke the method for `Node` rather than `AddNode`. Thus, `accept()` is necessary to get the "real" type of instance as follow:

```
public class AddNode extends Node implements IVisitable{
    void accept(IVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this)
    }
}
```

However, the type could be directly extract from instance in python. The `Visitor` could be implement as follow:

```
class Visitor(object):
    def visit(self, node):
        classname = node.__class__.__name__
        _visit = getattr(self, '_visit_'+classname)
        _visit(node)
    def _visit_AddNode(self, node):
        pass
```

Then, we could visit the node by using `visit()` directly

```
node = AddNode()
visitor = Visitor()
visitor.visit(node)
```

This way is more natural and simpler. Why do people still implement Visitor design pattern in python with `accept()`?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't think that my answer will resolve your question completely, but anyway:

1. when you remove `accept` method from the nodes you check it stops being Visitor pattern implementation (as it's clearly seen [at the diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern));
2. the way you wrote the code works only for the languages supporting introspection in a way, which allows to dynamically get the class of an instance ([type introspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection)). We have tools to do that in Python, but in other languages that can be not so easy to implement / pleasant to read.

There's another thread devoted to the problem on stackoverflow: "[What is the point of accept() method in Visitor pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132178/what-is-the-point-of-accept-method-in-visitor-pattern)". You can find here a lot of interesting details, e.g. case when node is a sophisticated compound structure and thus delegates `accept` method call to its parts.