# What is the need for `accept` method in Visitor pattern

Tags: java, visitor-pattern

I'm looking at the explanation of the visitor pattern [here](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-visitor) which shows the following code:

```
public class ShoppingCart {
  public double calculatePostage() {
    PostageVisitor visitor = new PostageVisitor();
    for(Visitable item: items) {
      item.accept(visitor);
    }

public class PostageVisitor implements Visitor {
  public void visit(Book book) {

public class Book implements Visitable{
  public void accept(Visitor vistor) {
    visitor.visit(this);
  }
```

From the standpoint of JavaScript developer the `accept` method seems redundant since the code **could be** written like this:

```
for(Visitable item: items) {
   // directly call visitor passing an item instead of doing so through `accept` method
   visitor.visit(item);  
}
```

Am I right to assume that this won't work because the compiler doesn't know which overloaded `visit` method of the visitor to execute?

As I understand the compiler understands which `visit` method to execute on the `visitor` with `accept` since it can match the type of `this` passed to the `visitor.visit(this)` method here:

```
public void accept(Visitor vistor) {
    visitor.visit(this);
}
```

**Edit:**

Just found that in addition to the great answers here [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132178/what-is-the-point-of-accept-method-in-visitor-pattern/16629618#16629618) also provides a lot of useful details.

Comment: Yes, you're right. If you had a unique visit(Visitable) method in the visitor, the visitor would have to make a series of instanceof checks to know what the concrete type of the Visitable is, and be able to access their specific properties and methods. That is exactly what the visitor pattern intends to avoid.

Comment: @JBNizet, cool, thanks. And as I understand since all items in `ShoppingCart` implement `Visitable` interface and the method is defined as `visit(Visitable)` on the visitor I wouldn't have any problems with the type mismatch during compilation?

Comment: This is generally true for most descriptions of design patterns that are expressed in terms of a statically typed language. In a language that isn't statically typed, you don't need most (or often, any) of the explicit scaffolding. Consider 'array-like' (javascript) or 'file-like' (python) objects.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16629618/2545680) from a different question seems to be relevant as well

Comment: Here's a general discussion of the broader issue by Peter Norvig that's worth a read. https://norvig.com/design-patterns/

Comment: @pvg, cool, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Am I right to assume that this won't work because the compiler doesn't know which overloaded visit method of the visitor to execute?

Absolutely. Visitor is for **double-dispatch**; `accept` executes the first leg of dispatch, because it is virtual on the `item`. The code inside `accept` executes the second leg of dispatch by letting the compiler pick the proper overload.

> As I understand the compiler understands which visit method to execute on the visitor with accept since it can match the type of this passed to the `visitor.visit(this)`

This is exactly right. I think the part that is confusing in this implementation of the visitor is the overload. It is much easier to see what's going on when instead of overloading `visit` you give each overload a separate name. In other words, instead of

```
public void visit(Book book);
public void visit(Cow cow);
public void visit(Island island);
```

you write

```
public void visitBook(Book book);
public void visitCow(Cow cow);
public void visitIsland(Island island);
```

Comment: thanks! I'll read more about double-dispatch technique. The code I'm looking at (in JavaScript though ) also uses name `visit` for method on the Visitable instead of `accept`. Have you seen that convention before?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com the name doesn't matter much, but it's more logical for a host to accept a visitor, and for the visitor to visit a host.

Answer (score 2):

> From the standpoint of JavaScript developer the accept method seems redundant since the code could be written like this:
>
> ```
> for(Visitable item: items) {
>     // directly call visitor passing an item instead of doing so through `accept` method
>     visitor.visit(item);  
> }
> ```

The code couldn't be written like that in JavaScript. To see why, let's first look at what the visitor looks like. In Java, it'd look like this:

```
void visit(Book book) { ... }
void visit(OtherThing otherThing) {...}
```

JavaScript doesn't have overloading like this, so the different visit methods would need different names. So it'd would look like this instead:

```
function visitBook(book) { ... }
function visitOtherThing(otherThing) { ... }
```

Now you clearly can't do `visitor.visit(item)` because there is no `visit` method. There are `visitBook` and `visitOtherThing`, but you don't know which of those to call because you don't what type of item you have. So you still need an accept method. Then a book's `accept` method would call `visitBook` and an `OtherThing`'s `accept` method would call `visitOtherThing`.

This is, in fact, what the visitor pattern in JavaScript usually looks like.

> Am I right to assume that this won't work because the compiler doesn't know which overloaded visit method of the visitor to execute?

Yes.

> As I understand the compiler understands which visit method to execute on the visitor with accept since it can match the type of this passed to the visitor.visit(this) method here

Exactly.

Comment: great, thanks! although my question was about Java, not JavaScript implementation, your answer still gave me some insights into the code I'm currently looking at in JavaScript. The code I'm looking at also uses name `visit` for method on the Visitable instead of `accept`. Have you seen that convention before?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com My goal was to make you understand why Java needs the `accept` method, by explaining why JavaScript needs it. It seemed to me that your confusion mainly stemmed from the misconception that the need for `accept` was Java-specific (or at least specific to languages with overloading), so I meant to clarify that.

Comment: "The code I'm looking at also uses name visit for method on the Visitable instead of accept. Have you seen that convention before?" Yes, but I don't like it. The visitor is the one who does the visiting. If anything the `accept` method should be called `byVisitedBy`, but that sounds stupid.

Comment: _My goal was to make yo..._ - I see now, additional thanks then for mixing up JavaScript :). Indeed, the `Visitor` I'm looking now implements 'visitElement', `visitText` and other methods just like you described. But it could be implemented in JS with just one method `visit` that inside does a bunch of `instanceof `checks and then decides what method to call, right?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com You can do that in Java, too, but then you're no longer implementing the visitor pattern.

Comment: hmm, I thought that the `visitor` pattern emphasize separation of logic from structure, so even with the implementation I mentioned above it still should be visitor. The `accept` part as I understand is just for `double-dispatch` mechanism, no?